# Check if the string matches the datatime

Tags: python-3.x, validation, datetime

I want the check if a value is matching the datetime pattern similar to this case:

```
def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

This is my string: `"2019-08-09T16:28:10.056+02:00"`. 
I find it difficult to write the pattern after the seconds. This is what I've got so far, but is not working:

```py
'%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.$fz'
```

Comment: `import re;dt.datetime.strptime(re.sub("\\..*","","2019-08-09T16:28:10.056+02:00."),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: From the error message about the expected date format it looks like you're not interested in everything after the first 10 character anyway. Couldn't you just throw away that irrelevant part of `date_text` and then parse it?

Comment: @Michael H. this was only an example, the values will always be with the format a gave